# laravel 6 route issue when try to redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am trying to redirect to login page when anyone hit home page in URL, but always it give error like

> **Route [admin/login] not defined.**

Many questions is there with same issue but does not solve the issue.

Also the same route work if directly type in URL then it work, but redirect from the `Authenticate.php` is not working.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
// Admin Routes

// Without auth
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/login', 'AdminLoginController@login');

});



Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Auth', 'middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {

  Route::get('/home', 'AdminLoginController@home');

});
```

**Authenticate.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {

            if ($request->is('admin') || $request->is('admin/*')) {
                return route('admin/login');
            } else if ($request->is('vendor') || $request->is('vendor/*')) {
                return route('vendor/login');
            } else {
                return route('login');
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't name your routes, so you can't call them like this, you need to use :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {
   // just add the name to the route to call route('login')
   Route::get('/login', 'AdminLoginController@login')->name('login');
});
```

Then you can call :

```
return route('login');
```

Or if you don't want to name your routes, use instead :

```
return redirect('admin/login');
```

**EDIT :**

My mistake, you use redirectTo function, so you just need to return a string, use this :

```
return 'admin/login';
```

Comment: i tried `return redirect('admin/login');` but it gives 

ErrorException
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Comment: Look my edit, I didn't see you were using redirectTo() function, just return a string in this case

Comment: But you should use route names, then use the `route()` function, it returns a string and this way you can be more flexible with your URI. Accept the answer please if it's ok

Comment: Yes , i am new to laravel so i am learning, please can you give any suggestions for multiauth login, like i am having multiple login like admins, vendors, users. so the approach i am using and anything i have to change then plz suggest me.